# Issue on blackberry where site will not change orientation and will not scroll horizontally

Tags: viewport, screen-orientation

When a users views my site on a Blackberry they are unable to scroll horizontally. This is important because the view port on the Blackberry is smaller than that of the width of the site. They can still scroll up and down just not side to side. The other thing is they cannot zoom out for the site either. Finally the site will not change orientation either. When testing on iPhone and iPad zooming and scrolling work fine.

Could it this be caused by a meta tag or view port setting? What are some of the things that could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue appears to be that in absence of a meta tag the Balckberry Browser will set its own viewport to the screen width of the device. This made it so that the rest of the page to the right of the device viewport was cut off and although users could scroll up and down they could not scroll side to side.

The issue was solved by adding a meta tag defining the viewport, its width, and a zoom level with scalability explicitly defined.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width = 1000, initial-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = yes">
```